# Alter table table_name Add @name INT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want column name as output parameter.If anyone knows then post your answer

```
DECLARE @Col-name INT 
SET @Col-name = 1

ALTER TABLE Table_Name ADD @Col-name INT
```

I tried this but not working.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Try to use dynamic SQL

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I can't find any way to read this question that starts to make sense. Output parameters exist in the context of stored procedures, but the code you show has no obvious relation to stored procs. `ALTER TABLE ... ADD` is used for adding columns to a table, but I've no idea what you think supplying an `int` there would do.

Comment: i want to add columns dynamically for temp table in stored procedure only.That's why i gave exapmle like that.

Comment: Okay, so what we have is, you have a problem, X. And you've decided (for some reason) that part of the *solution* to that problem is to add (many) columns to a temp table dynamically. It's still not clear what output parameters have to do with this, and the words "temp table" have only started to appear in your comments. Could you maybe describe to us the *problem* that you're trying to solve?

Comment: I found the solution..  Declare @One INT = 1 ALTER TABLE Table_Name [@one] INT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant INPUT parameter. You have to use dynamic SQL for this type of operations:

```
DECLARE @Col_name varchar(50); SET @Col_name = 'Column_name';
DECLARE @Col_type varchar(10); SET @Col_type = 'INT';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(50); SET @sql = N'ALTER TABLE Table_name ADD ' + @Col_name + ' ' + @Col_type;         
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: I got solution for this. Declare @One INT = 1 ALTER TABLE Table_Name [@one] INT

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)='alter table Table_Name
add' +@Col-name+'(type)'

print @sql 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Ya it's fine. But i have to add so many number of columns for temp table in stored procedure.I think, for every column exec sp_executesql is complex

Comment: I got solution for this. Declare @One INT = 1   ALTER TABLE Table_Name   [@one] INT

Comment: @user3410240 - all that does is add a column named `@one` to the table. That column bears *no* relation to the `@One` variable you've previously `Declare`d and initialised.